# Vue - Mixing options api with composition api lifecycle hooks

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-options-api

Recently I found out that composition API lifecycle hooks can be used within options API components.

For instance, I'm using `beforeUnmount` hook inside `mounted` of composition API, and the hook is called correctly.

https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-onunmounted-vue-3-2-4e8x61?file=/src/components/test1.vue

There is not much information regarding this topic yet. On the [documentation page](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html), there is a hint saying:

> For shared usage of lifecycle hooks, see [Guide - Lifecycle Hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html)

But it leads to an incomplete page with little information regarding this subject.

So I wonder if it is acceptable using composition API lifecycle hooks this way? Am I missing something?

Comment: . It's acceptable to do this because it's not punishable, but there are no good reasons to do this. Composition api is supposed to be used directly in setup, any other usages should be explicitly allowed, or should be confirmed with trial and error. This is the case here. Since this is not documented behaviour, it can change any moment